# Can I add a field to the app_events_intraday table in BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, etl

I am currently extracting my Firebase event data from BigQuery to an onsite database for analysis. I extract the Firebase intraday table(s) along with the previous 4 days (since previous days' tables [continue to be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066693/1973199)) every time I run the ETL job. Since there is no key or unique ID for events, I am deleting & re-inserting the past 4 days of data locally in order to refresh the data from BigQuery.

Would it be possible for me to create a new field called event_dim.etl_status  on the intraday table to keep track of events that have been moved locally? And if so, would this field make its way into the app_events_yyyymmdd table once it is renamed from *_intraday to *_yyyymmdd?

**Edit:**
Some more context based on comments from dsesto:

1. A magical Firebase-BigQuery wizard automatically copies/renames the Event "intraday" table into a daily table, so I have no way to reproduce or test this. It is part of the Firebase->BigQuery black box.
2. Since I only have a production environment (Firebase has no mechanism for a sandbox environment), testing this theory would require potentially breaking my production environment which is why I posed a "is it possible" scenario in case someone else has done something similar.

Comment: Hi! I would recommend you to reformulate the question, given that you are posting quite a subjective question like `you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”`, which [is not likely to get an answer in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You should try asking a more specific question that can be more easily addressed, or at least more understandable. I would recommend that you first try to develop your approach and if you have specific issues with it, maybe you can come back for help. Thanks!

Comment: In any case, let me share with you these links for [adding columns to a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_columns_to_a_tables_schema_definition) and [renaming a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762968/4482491) by copying it with a different name. If you are adding a column to the already existing table `app_events_intraday`, it will not be removed if you copy it into a new `app_events_yyyymmdd` table.