# how to convert a non-partitioned table into a partitioned one

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

How to rename a TABLE in BigQuery using StandardSQL or LegacySQL in order to partition a table which was not previously partitioned?
I'm trying with StandardSQL but it is giving following error,

RENAME TABLE `dataset.old_table_name` TO `dataset.new_table_name`;

Statement not supported: RenameStatement at [1:1]

Does it mean there is no any method(SQL QUERY) Which can rename a table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to rename a table without re creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756094/how-to-rename-a-table-without-re-creating-it)

Comment: @Pentium10 I saw that question, I was a year ago. So I thought If now there is any way to rename it. Because my old table doesn't contain partition and new table will contain partition. So I just want to change from non-partition table to partition-table. If there any way to do this without coping entire table.

Comment: you need to script it

Comment: Instead of rename, seems the question would be "how to convert a non-partitioned table into a partitioned one"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to change from non-partition table to partition-table

You can achieve this in two steps process

Step 1 - Export your table to Google Cloud Storage

Step 2 - Load file from GCS back to GBQ into new table with partitioned column

Both are free of charge
Still, have in mind some limitatins of partitioned tables - like number of partitions for example  - it is 4000 per table as of today - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not possible to rename table in Bigquery as explained in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#renaming_a_table). You will have to create another table by following the steps given by Mikhail. Notice there is still some charge from table storage, but it is minimal. See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#option_2_exporting_your_data_and_loading_it_into_a_new_table) for detail information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query, it will create a new table with distinct records from old table with partition on given column.

```
     create or replace table `dataset.new_table` PARTITION BY DATE(date_time_column) as select distinct * from `dataset.old_table`
```